# Semi-advanced Outlook rule

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

I have a particular need for a rule in Outlook, and I don't know if it's possible to achieve.

I belong to 3 different mailing lists, and messages sent to them are moved to 3 different folders. But when one single mail is sent to all 3 of them, it gets replicated to all folders.

That is the correct behaviour, but I'd like to create a rule so that if that happens, only one copy of the mail remains, for example:

- if it contains mailing A, B, C; it's moved to folder A only.
- if it contains mailing B, C; it's moved to folder B only.
- if it contains mailing C; it's moved to folder C.

I tried "stop processing more rules", and it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that the mail arrives 3 different times actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do. You need three rules in this order.

```
#1
from C
move it to the C folder
except if from A or B
stop processing

#2
from B
move it to the B folder
except if from A
stop processing

#3
from A
move it to the A folder
stop processing
```

This assumes, of course, that all the addresses are on the message.